# R apply list of functions to each row of a matrix, with functions taking rows as inputs

Tags: r, machine-learning, functional-programming, apply, lapply

## Minimal Working Example Set Up - Reproducing the list of functions

I have the following closure/factory of functions

```
rbf <- function(centroid){
  rbfdot <- function(x){
    return(
      exp(-sum((x - centroid)^2) / sigmasq)
    )
  }
  return(rbfdot)
}
```

Each of such functions takes a vector `x` and returns a measure of distance of `x` from some `centroid` vector. I have a list of such functions, created as follows

```
# Define a random sigmasq, it doens't matter
sigmasq <- 1
# Create a matrix where each row is a centroid
centroids <- matrix(1:6, 3, 2)  # 3 centoids. They are vectors with 2 entries
# Create list of rbfdot functions
rbfs <- apply(centroids, 1, rbf)
```

## The Problem - What I need your help with

Suppose now I have a matrix `X` with `2` columns (basically same as the centroids) and, say, `10` rows:

```
X <- matrix(1:20, 10, 2)
```

All I want to do is to apply all the functions in the list `rbfs` to each row of the matrix `X`.

## What I can do

I can apply one of the `rbfdot` functions contained in `rbfs` to the whole of X, like this

```
apply(X, 1, rbfs[[1]])
```

Which does indeed return a vector of length `10`, as expected. How do I apply all of the functions in `rbfs` to each row of `X` at once?

Comment: I might have found a workaround, although I find it quite inelegant. Basically I apply the last function to the whole of X
`mapply(function(f) apply(X, 1, f), rbfs)`

Comment: I don't have a different solution either  but I would use `lapply`. `lapply(rbfs, function(f) apply(X, 1, f))`